# Can Leiningen install (and let my Clojure project use) Java packages directly from Maven?

Tags: java, maven, clojure, leiningen

I'm not used to the Java / Maven ecosystem, but I'm happy using the Clojure / Leiningen / Clojars one.

So can I simply put the name of a package from Maven.org in my project.clj file, the way I'd put a clojar reference? Or is there more to it?

Comment: Well, did you try it? Seems like a great opportunity for an experiment.

Comment: Yes, lein will check Maven Central and Clojars for any artifacts

Comment: What's an "artifact"? Is it the same as a jar file / package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer - yes.

Read about [Maven coordinates](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) to understand terminology - artifacts, groups and versions. It is common with Leiningen - see [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#artifact-ids-groups-and-versions).

And yes, you just put package coordinates from Maven to `project.clj` and off you go. The translation is trivial. If you have for example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

then in `project.clj` it will look like

```
:dependencies [[log4j/log4j "1.2.17"]]
```

Comment: Thanks. That example conversion is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for and is really hard to search for when you don't know the terminology.